# Cómo truncar un numero a 2 decimales (10,2)?

Tags: javascript

Tengo algo asi como un cronometro y necesito que al llegar a 0.99 pase a 1.0 y asi 1.99 a 2.0

```
var c = 0;
function myCounter() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ++c;
}
///// boton //////
<button onClick="myTimer = setInterval(myCounter, 1000)" class="button button-large withmargin">Empezar</button>
        <center>
        <h1><p id="demo">Empieza contador.</p></h1>
        </center>
        <button onClick="clearInterval(myTimer)" class="button button-large withmargin">Pausar</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui un ejemplo de cronometro:

```js
var centesimas = 0;
var segundos = 0;
var minutos = 0;
var horas = 0;
function inicio () {
 control = setInterval(cronometro,10);
 document.getElementById("inicio").disabled = true;
 document.getElementById("parar").disabled = false;
 document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
 document.getElementById("reinicio").disabled = false;
}
function parar () {
 clearInterval(control);
 document.getElementById("parar").disabled = true;
 document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = false;
}
function reinicio () {
 clearInterval(control);
 centesimas = 0;
 segundos = 0;
 minutos = 0;
 horas = 0;
 Centesimas.innerHTML = ":00";
 Segundos.innerHTML = ":00";
 Minutos.innerHTML = ":00";
 Horas.innerHTML = "00";
 document.getElementById("inicio").disabled = false;
 document.getElementById("parar").disabled = true;
 document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
 document.getElementById("reinicio").disabled = true;
}
function cronometro () {
 if (centesimas < 99) {
  centesimas++;
  if (centesimas < 10) { centesimas = "0"+centesimas }
  Centesimas.innerHTML = ":"+centesimas;
 }
 if (centesimas == 99) {
  centesimas = -1;
 }
 if (centesimas == 0) {
  segundos ++;
  if (segundos < 10) { segundos = "0"+segundos }
  Segundos.innerHTML = ":"+segundos;
 }
 if (segundos == 59) {
  segundos = -1;
 }
 if ( (centesimas == 0)&&(segundos == 0) ) {
  minutos++;
  if (minutos < 10) { minutos = "0"+minutos }
  Minutos.innerHTML = ":"+minutos;
 }
 if (minutos == 59) {
  minutos = -1;
 }
 if ( (centesimas == 0)&&(segundos == 0)&&(minutos == 0) ) {
  horas ++;
  if (horas < 10) { horas = "0"+horas }
  Horas.innerHTML = horas;
 }
}
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#contenedor{
 margin: 10px auto;
 width: 540px;
 height: 115px;
}
.reloj{
 float: left;
 font-size: 80px;
 font-family: Courier,sans-serif;
 color: #363431;
}
.boton{
 outline: none;
 border: 1px solid #363431;
 color: white;
 width: 128px;
 height: 30px;
 text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px black;
 font-size: 20px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-image: linear-gradient(#3aad02,#2c6f05);
}
.boton:active{
 background-image: linear-gradient(#2c6f05,#3aad02);
}
.boton:hover{
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px #3aad02;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <div class="reloj" id="Horas">00</div>
  <div class="reloj" id="Minutos">:00</div>
  <div class="reloj" id="Segundos">:00</div>
  <div class="reloj" id="Centesimas">:00</div>
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="inicio" value="Start &#9658;" onclick="inicio();">
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="parar" value="Stop &#8718;" onclick="parar();" disabled>
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="continuar" value="Resume &#8634;" onclick="inicio();" disabled>
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="reinicio" value="Reset &#8635;" onclick="reinicio();" disabled>
 </div>
```